# Transform trip movement data frame into residence counts summary data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data-wrangling

I'm attempting to find out how many herons are at a lake at a given time, and how that total changes over time. Unfortunately, the data set I have is not organized by lake or even heron tag ID, but by migratory trip number. I want to know how many birds are at each lake in a given time frame. How can I wrangle the starting data set to get to the finish data set? I've attempted to make a time series data frame as a mid-processing step, but the time series data frames I found in other Stack Overflow posts isn't quite what I'm going for. Below are example data frames and my attempts.

```
# Start data frame
#  Great blue heron (Ardea herodias) flights migration data
bird_flights = data.frame(species = c("Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias","Ardea herodias", "Ardea herodias"),
                          subspecies = c("herodias", "herodias", "wardi", "herodias", "herodias", "herodias", "herodias", "herodias", "herodias"),
                          trip_number = c(1:9),
                          tag_id = c(4001, 4042, 5959, 4001, 4001, 4001, 4042, 4042, 4042),
                          departure_date   = c("10/15/2021", "10/10/2021", "10/2/2021", "11/20/2021", "3/1/2022", "3/20/2022", "11/20/2021", "3/3/2022", "3/20/2022"),
                          departure_lake = c("Seneca", "Seneca", "Otter Bay", "Marion", "Bee Haven Bay", "Marion", "Marion", "Bee Haven Bay", "Marion"),
                          arrival_date = c("10/30/2021", "10/29/2021", "10/12/2021", "12/5/2021", "3/15/2022", "4/5/2022", "12/5/2021", "3/17/2022", "4/6/2022"),
                          arrival_lake = c("Marion", "Marion", "Bee Haven Bay", "Bee Haven Bay", "Marion", "Seneca", "Bee Haven Bay", "Marion", "Cayuga"))

# Goal: End data frame
# Lake Populations and Residence Times for The Migratory Year (October - May) 
# Note: I did not write lines for Marion Lake or Bee Haven Bay, but this shows the data structure with three example lakes.
lake_counts = data.frame(lake_name = c("Seneca", "Seneca", "Seneca", "Seneca", "Cayuga", "Cayuga", "Otter Bay", "Otter Bay"),
                         start_time = c("10/1/2021", "10/10/2021", "10/15/2021", "10/20/2022", "10/1/2021", "4/6/2022", "10/1/2021", "10/2/2021"),
                         end_time = c("10/10/2021", "10/15/2021", "10/20/2022", "5/31/2023", "4/6/2022", "5/31/2023", "10/2/2021", "5/31/2022"),
                         count = c(2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))

# Attempted Data Processing

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Add day-of-year columns
df1 = bird_flights %>%
        mutate(day_of_year_arrive = lubridate::yday(arrival_date),
               day_of_year_depart = lubridate::yday(departure_date))


# Middle Data Frame: group data by lake_name and arrival day-of-year, then summarize by adding the heron tag_id counts 
# Problem: Doesn't take into account departure for residence times
df2 = df1 %>% 
   dplyr::group_by(lake_name, day_of_year_arrive) %>%
   dplyr::summarize( n = count(unique(tag_id)))
```

Notes: If I assume this data set is for the migratory season (October 01- May 31). If I have zero prior trips, I assume the bird was at the lake at the start of the season. If I have zero subsequent trip, I assume the bird remains at the lake until the end of the season.

We follow three herons. We can see two herons (tag IDs 4001 and 4042) start their migration at Lake Seneca in New York. They both stop over at Lake Marion, then wind up at Bee Haven Bay, Florida for the winter. Then in the spring heron 4001 returns to Lake Seneca. Heron 4042 goes to Lake Cayuga, NY in the Spring. Heron 5959 begins its winter in Otter Bay in Florida and then spends the rest of the season at Bee Haven Bay. It never migrates North.

I want my final answer to demonstrate how herons begin at Lake Seneca, but then slowly leave in the migration, and eventually return in the Spring. Meanwhile Bee Haven Bay slowly increases in birds for the winter, which begin to depart in Spring. In real life I have many more  Northern and Southern lakes, but these two will work for our example.

Comment: It looks like you have data showing herons left Seneca on 10/10 and 10/15. What assumptions should be made to assume there are no other herons at Seneca or that those two were there since 10/1?

Comment: on which dates does the season start and end?

Comment: Assume that those two were there since 10/1. We are only tracking those two herons from Senaca and we can assume no other tagged herons were present in the lake or left the lake at any time.

Comment: The season starts on 10/01/2021 and ends on 05/31/2022